# Tailwind and dynamic classes seem to be missing

Tags: css, laravel, dynamic, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I'm with Tailwind in a Laravel App. While using some TW classes with dynamic params in any Blade view as:

```
<div class="bg-[url('{{ $myBackgroundImageWithPublicSubPath }}')]" > Any content </div>
```

it does not works when rendering the page in the browser. Inspecting the source seems like that class was missing.

As TW docs clearly said (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) TW struggle with dynamic classes because they are using regular expressions inspecting the source code in order to prune the final css bundle, then it miss the proper class as not find it in the view's script.

Do you found any walk around to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

you're correct that Tailwind CSS relies on static analysis of your code to generate its styles, and dynamic classes like the one you're trying to use won't be included in the final CSS output.

One workaround is to use inline styles in this case. Laravel allows you to echo variables directly into your Blade templates, so you could do something like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{ asset($myBackgroundImageWithPublicSubPath) }}');" class="bg-cover">
    Any content
</div>
```